# Spivak Calculus Chapter $5$, Problem $6$ (ii)

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Suppose the functions $f$ and $g$ have the following property: for all $\varepsilon>0$ and all $x$, \begin{align}\text{if } 0< |x-2|&< \sin ^2{\left(
\frac{\varepsilon ^2}{9}\right)} +\varepsilon \text{, then } |f(x)-2|<\varepsilon \\
\text{if } 0< |x-2|&<\varepsilon^2 \text{, then } |g(x)-4|<\varepsilon
\end{align}
For each $\varepsilon>0$ find a $\delta >0 $ such that, for all $x$,

(ii)$$\text{ if } 0<|x-2|<\delta\text{, then }|f(x)g(x)-8|<\varepsilon$$

I thought: $$|f(x)g(x)-8|=|f(x)g(x)-2g(x)+2g(x)-8|=|g(x)(f(x)-2)+2(g(x)-4)|$$ so with a choice of $\delta$ similar to this $\delta=\min\left(\sin ^2{\left(
\frac{\varepsilon ^2}{9}\right)} +\varepsilon ,\varepsilon ^2/16 \right)$ and the triangle inequality, we can get: $$|g(x)(f(x)-2)+2(g(x)-4)|< \varepsilon |g(x)|+ \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$

So what's left is to show that $|g(x)|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$. But I can't figure out how to go about doing this and I'm not sure if there even is a way since the only way to get a bound for $g$ is from $-\varepsilon +4 \leq g(x) \leq \varepsilon+4$ and since $\varepsilon>0$ we can't get a tighter bound than $4 \leq g(x)\leq 4 \implies g(x)=4$. The solutions aren't very helpful either since the choice of $\delta$ there seems to be suggesting another way of going about it

> We need
>
> $$|f(x)-2|<\min\left( 1,\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|4|+1)}\right)\quad \text{and} \quad |g(x)-4|< \frac{\varepsilon}{2|2|+1} $$
> so we need
> $$0<|x-2|<\min \left( \sin ^2 \left(\frac{[\min(1,\varepsilon/10)]^2]}{9} \right)+\min(1,\varepsilon /10), [\min(1,\varepsilon/6]^2\right)=\delta$$

And another question: if we had a function $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ where $D_h=D_f \cap D_g$ then would my above method be sufficient to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} h(x) =8 $? Since $\varepsilon |g(x)|+\varepsilon /2$ for all $x$ is of the form $C \varepsilon$ where $C\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and thus can get arbitrarily small. But in most cases where we have our $\varepsilon$ to be of that form $C\varepsilon$ at the end of the proof and we would like to get it to be $\varepsilon$, we can alter the $\varepsilon$ from the start to $\varepsilon /C$ but it seems like it isn't possible to do so here. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I think your first use of triangle inequality should be $\epsilon |g(x)| +2\epsilon$.

Comment: For your main question, you are not required to show for all x, only for x close to 2, for which you already know g(x) is close to 4.

Comment: I changed the choice of $\varepsilon$ for $f$ from $\varepsilon$ to $\varepsilon /4$ in order to be able to find a bound of $1/2$ for $g$ and write $\varepsilon/2 +\varepsilon /2=\varepsilon$. Does it make a difference?

Comment: In general, if for given epsilon you can find delta such that a desired quantity is no more than 100epsilon, then you are done as you can define epsilon’ as epsilon/100 and repick your delta accordingly (using epsilon’).

Comment: By the way it looks like you are playing with the wrong inequality, so changing that for f would give the bound $\epsilon|g(x)|/4 +2\epsilon$.

Comment: That's right, thank you. Regarding the previous comment: This is what I was trying to convey in my last paragraph but the fact that the epsilon in this case is dependent to delta confuses me. When you say 'repick your delta accordingly', here the repicking of the delta involves messing with the epsilon and that's where I get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to anticipate the correct factors you will need to get a desired quantity less than $\epsilon$, it is usually easier to show that you can get a desired quantity within $c\epsilon$ (for some $c$, say $c=100$ or $c=7$), then do a post-facto correction.

1. Step 1: Fix $\epsilon>0$. Motivated directly by the given info (without playing any preemptive scaling tricks) choose:
   $$ \delta = \min[\sin^2(\epsilon^2/9) + \epsilon, \epsilon^2]$$
   Then for $x$ satisfying $0<|x-2|<\delta$ we get
   $$ |f(x)-2|<\epsilon, |g(x)-4|<\epsilon$$
   and so by triangle inequality
   \begin{align}
   quantity=|g(x)(f(x)-2) + 2(g(x)-4)|&\leq |g(x)||f(x)-2|+2|g(x)-4| \\
   &< |g(x)|\epsilon + 2\epsilon\\
   &\leq (4+\epsilon)\epsilon + 2\epsilon \\
   &=6\epsilon + \epsilon^2
   \end{align}
2. Step 2: We notice if we assume $0<\epsilon\leq 1$ we can make $\epsilon^2\leq \epsilon$. So: Given any $\epsilon$ that satisfies $0<\epsilon\leq 1$ we can choose $\delta>0$ so that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ implies
   $$quantity < 7\epsilon$$
3. Step 3: So given any $\beta>0$, we can define $\epsilon = \min[\beta/7,1]$. So $0<\epsilon\leq 1$ and by step 2 we can choose $\delta>0$ so that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ implies
   $$quantity < 7\epsilon \leq \beta$$

---

The above is a basic way to reason through the problem. If you want you can then write the proof "backwards":

- Fix $\beta>0$.
- Define $\epsilon = \min[\beta/7, 1]$ [this is unmotivated to the reader].
- Define $\delta = \min[sin^2(\epsilon^2/9)+\epsilon, \epsilon^2]$.
- Show that $quantity< 7\epsilon \leq \beta$

Comment: PS: I much prefer working with $\leq$ as opposed to $<$. For these proofs it is tiresome to check if the strict inequality actually holds.

Comment: Does Spivak’s suggested proof avoid checking for the monotonicity of $\varepsilon \mapsto \sin ^2(\varepsilon /9)+ \varepsilon$?

Comment: Is the delta used for the third step the same as the initial delta?

Comment: It looks like my proof does not really use the "step 4" which was my retrospective worry about whether or not $\sin^2(\epsilon/9)+\epsilon$ is nondecreasing for $\epsilon>0$ (it is nondecreasing for $\epsilon \in [0, v]$ for some $v>0$). But this issue does not really matter in this context.